# Reading attribute in OnAction Executing in asp.net mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having an action and attribute as following, i have over-ridden  `OnActionExecuting` and want to read attribute in that method

```
[MyAttribute(integer)]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
}


protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    //here i want to read integer passed to action using Attribute
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try it:

**Controller**

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
  foreach (var filter in filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (MyAttribute), false).Cast<MyAttribute>())
  {
    var desiredValue = filter.Parameter;
  }

  base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

**Filter**

```
public class MyAttribute : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
  private readonly int _parameter;

  public MyAttribute(int parameter)
  {
    _parameter = parameter;
  }

  public int Parameter { get { return _parameter; } }

  public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
  {
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

Comment: For a complete explanation of Action Filters, check out this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs